# How to show the actual error message instead of custom error when using Web API 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2

I have build my API using ASP.NET web API 2 and am using [WebAPiThrottle](https://github.com/stefanprodan/WebApiThrottle) to throttle the requests, as shown below:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   // more code...

   config.MessageHandlers.Add(new ThrottlingHandler()
   {
      Policy = new ThrottlePolicy(perMinute: 10)
      {
         IpThrottling = true,
         EndpointThrottling = true,
      },
      Repository = new CacheRepository()
   });
```

Now I try the above code on Dev and Prod, environment... after sending too many reuqests here what I see:

### Dev environment

Error: 429

> API calls quota exceeded! maximum admitted 4 per Minute

[image]

### Prod environment

Error: 429

> The custom error module does not recognize this error

[image]

I don't want to send the above message to client. I want to send the actual error... how can I prevent this from happening?

This is what I have in my WebConfig:

```
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="/Error/NotFound">
   <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Error/NotFound" />
   <error statusCode="500" redirect="/Error/ServerError" />
</customErrors>
```

and

```
<httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly">
   <remove statusCode="404" />
   <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
   <remove statusCode="500" />
   <error statusCode="500" path="/Error/ServerError" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```